# Kotlin Android Int

Tags: math, kotlin, decimal

My issue is I currently have a value that is £17.40, this is then converted into Euros which becomes €20.01. when selecting the button which which would round up the amount it reads €20.00 but should read €30.00 (with €30 being the next whole amount to pay with).

```
private fun getNextLogicalCashAmount(currentAmount: Double = getBasket()?.getAmountRemaining() ?: 0.00): Double
{

    var amount = ((Math.ceil(currentAmount) / 10.00).toInt() * 10).toDouble()
    if (amount <= currentAmount )
    {
        amount += 10


    }
    return amount
}

private fun setConvertedAmount(amount: Double)
{
    val nativeFormatter = LocalityHelper.getNumberFormatter()
    converted_amount?.visibility = if (amount > 0.00) View.VISIBLE else View.INVISIBLE
    converted_amount?.text = getString(R.string.same_as_amount, nativeFormatter.format(convertBack(amount)))
}

/**
 * Return the custom amount entered into the EditText as a Double.
 */
private fun getCustomAmount(): Double
{
    return try
    {
        custom_amount?.text.toString().toDouble()
    }
    catch (e: Exception)
    {
        0.00
    }
}

private fun convert(amount: Double): Double = providers.getCurrencyConverter().convert(
        amount,
        providers.getMarketOptions().getCurrencyCode(),
        providers.getStoreOptions().getForeignCurrencyCode()!!
)

private fun convertBack(amount: Double): Double = providers.getCurrencyConverter().convert(
        amount,
        providers.getStoreOptions().getForeignCurrencyCode()!!,
        providers.getMarketOptions().getCurrencyCode()
)

private fun takePayment(amount: Double, foreignAmount: Double)
{
    if (amount > 0.00 && foreignAmount > 0.00)
    {
        CashDrawerDialog().setListener { addPayment(amount, foreignAmount, it) }.show(this)
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, R.string.enter_valid_amount, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

It seems I am still picking up the value from the £. So when the £ reaches £20, the € will change to €30.00, but when the the foreign currency is at €20.1 it will still show as €20.00.

- [Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3cr2.png)
- [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEhKl.png)
- [Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4yd7.png)
- [Image 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6Zlq.png)

Comment: Not the answer to your question as such, but you will remove a lof ot ambiguity by using the Kotlin Long type instead of Double to work with currency values. While Double seems like a logical fit, it can introduce all sorts of problems when doing currency arithmetic. Using a Long means that you must work in hundredths of the currency unit (pence, cents, centimes etc) and then you must move the decimal point two to the left when displaying.

Comment: Your function `getNextLogicalCashAmount()` works fine, when passed 20.1 returns 30.0

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/.  And https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/228584 and https://dzone.com/articles/never-use-float-and-double-for-monetary-calculatio and https://floating-point-gui.de/ and http://wiki.c2.com/?FloatingPointCurrency and http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2014/09/floating-point-and-currency/ and…  TLDR: **DO NOT Store Currency Values In Floating-Point!**  Use `BigDecimal` or `Long` instead.